# What is the hexadecimal notation to get 0.5 as a float literal in F#

Tags: f#

In F#, if I want to use hexadecimal notation to declare a double-precision float literal using `LF` suffix with the literal value of 0.0 I can do the following:

```
let zeroFloat = 0x0000_0000_0000_0000LF // returns 0.0 as float
```

Now if I want the float literal value of 0.5, I can do:

```
let floatOneHalf = 0.5
let floatOneHalfScientific = 5.0e-1
```

But what is the hexadecimal notation to get 0.5?

```
let floatOneHalfHex = 0x????_????_????_????LF // should return 0.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let x = 0x3fe0_0000_0000_0000LF`

should do it.

See https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/ for more info.